# Swipe is not working in Appium Android Webview

Tags: java, android, selenium, webview, appium

I am using the below code to swipe on a web view

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mainSec\"]/section/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/input[1]")).sendKeys(username);

 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mainSec\"]/section/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/input[2]")).sendKeys(password);
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mainSec\"]/section/div[2]/div/div[3]/button")).click();
 Thread.sleep(20000);
 driver.swipe(944, 1100, 110, 1100, 2000);
```

getting below error

On the Appium Server

```
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/71ff38f1-3e77-44ef-b4af-d2ab69970112                        
 /touch/perform {"actions":[{"action":"press","options": {"x":944,"y":1100}},{"action":"wait","options":{"ms":2000}},{"action":"moveTo","options":{"x":110,"y":1100}},{"action":"release","options":{}}]}
> info: JSONWP Proxy: Proxying [POST /wd/hub/session/71ff38f1-3e77-44ef-b4af-d2ab69970112/touch/perform] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/session/9effe9253998eaad03f14d1cc5ef148c/touch/perform] with body: {"actions":[{"action":"press","options":{"x":944,"y":1100}},{"action":"wait","options":{"ms":2000}},{"action":"moveTo","options":{"x":110,"y":1100}},{"action":"release","options":{}}]}
> info: JSONWP Proxy: Got response with status 404: unknown command: session/9effe9253998eaad03f14d1cc5ef148c/touch/perform
```

On Eclipse TestNG

```
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
 Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:16:47'
 System info: host: 'IN2084073W1', ip: '10.165.162.203', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_21'
 Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
```

Comment: You can refer to this question, it's a bit similar to yours : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34307482/how-can-i-swipe-horizontally-after-locating-an-element-using-appium-in-an-androi

Answer (score 2):

Use TouchAction class to perform swipe. Like this:

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver).longPress(longPress).moveTo(moveTo).release();
action.perform();
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply. i have tried with the code you have provided. Now i am not getting any error on appium server or TestNG. My method got passed. But unable to see the element are getting swiped. Please help. Here is the code                                                       TouchAction act = new TouchAction(driver);
act.longPress(604, 762,1000).moveTo(117, 762).release();

Comment: @Hashili did you find a solution ? I am having similar problems also, thanks.

Comment: @DrPatience yes it worked for me on trying with driver.swipe method with x,y co-ordinates and delay..... if this not worked for you... just switch the context to NATIVE APP just before this swipe method and try

Answer (score 0):

May be you can switch context to native, like

```
driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
```

then, swipe can work, like

```
driver.swipe(500, 1600, 500, 600, 1000);
```