# How can i swipe horizontally after locating an element using Appium in an Android app?

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, testng, swipe, appium

I have used the following code, but it is not working:

```
int startX = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='android.widget.FrameLayout' and @index='1']")).getLocation.getX();
int startY = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='android.widget.FrameLayout' and @index='1']")).getLocation.getY();
```

and the error I get is:

```
getLocation cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

Comment: Use [Swipe](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/appium/ruby_lib/Appium%2FTouchAction%3Aswipe) method to swipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you should try getting location as `getLocation()`instead of: `.getLocation.getY()`.

Secondly you can implement swipe/scroll in all directions using:

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);

        int startY = element1.getLocation().getY() + (element1.getSize().getHeight() / 2);
        int startX = element1.getLocation().getX() + (element1.getSize().getWidth() / 2);

        int endX = element2.getLocation().getX() + (element2.getSize().getWidth() / 2);
        int endY = element2.getLocation().getY() + (element2.getSize().getHeight() / 2);

        action.press(startX, startY).waitAction(2000).moveTo(endX, endY).release().perform();
```

Comment: Thank you, but it tells me pull @Test Annotation in the class level 
and after i put it it tell me that annotation should be in that method !
 The problem comes in that line
  TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
also 

        action.press(startX, startY).waitAction(2000).moveTo(endX, endY).release().perform();
it tells me:  add cast to action

Comment: Please provide code fragment and particular error. Make sure that you have imported : import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction; Also Consider using Page Object pattern: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects And write your tests cases in different classes, then run them from another class (Here you can use @Test Annotation).

Comment: Hi,
How can i swipe horizontally from Right WebElement to extreme Left WebElement?

Comment: Can we handle this with window size instead of element reference?

Comment: In-order to swipe from left to right need to interchange the startx,starty from press to moveto. Similarly vice versa for endx, endy from moveto to press.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void horizontalScroll()
{
    size=driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int x_start=(int)(size.width*0.60);
    int x_end=(int)(size.width*0.30);
    int y=130;
    driver.swipe(x_start,y,x_end,y,4000);
}
```

Best Tutorial to understand horizontal scroll - [CLICK HERE](http://www.qaautomated.com/2016/02/how-to-do-horizontal-scroll-in-appium.html)

Comment: @anuja Jain: swipe method is deprecated and not working now.
please refer this link for more updates:
https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/AppiumDriver.html