# How to drag slider to certain string

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, slider

On this page: https://www.wedoqa.com/
I have to swip slider to certan quotes.
(Eversave, Simplymap and Pattern publishing)

For now my code looks like this:

```
package test;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Users/goran/Desktop/Alas/geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        search.sendKeys("wedoqa.com\n");
        search.submit();

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        WebElement firstResult = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[@class='r']/a"));
        firstResult.click();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        WebElement testimonialsReferences = driver.findElement(By.id("testimonials"));
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", testimonialsReferences);

        Thread.sleep(2000);     

        //HERE I NEED TO FIND ELEMENT AND SWIPE TO CERTAIN QUOTE
    }
}
```

So, it's those ones:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you should refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34307482/how-can-i-swipe-horizontally-after-locating-an-element-using-appium-in-an-androi?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @SimonN It's Appium for android...
Do you have some answer for my question? :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use drag and drop 
see below method

```
/**
 * @author mbn
 * @Date 05/01/2018
 * @Purpose This method will perform a drag and drop
 * @param fromWebElement --> element to drag from
 * @param toWebElement --> element to release to
 * @return N/A
 */
public static void dragAndDrop_Method2(WebElement fromWebElement, WebElement toWebElement) {

    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(fromWebElement).moveToElement(toWebElement).release(toWebElement)
            .build();
    dragAndDrop.perform();
}
```

or this method

```
/**
 * @author mbn
 * @Date 05/01/2018
 * @Purpose This method will perform a drag and drop
 * @param fromWebElement --> element to drag from
 * @param toWebElement --> element to release to
 * @return N/A
 */
public static void dragAndDrop_Method3(WebElement fromWebElement, WebElement toWebElement)
        throws InterruptedException {

    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.clickAndHold(fromWebElement).moveToElement(toWebElement).perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    builder.release(toWebElement).build().perform();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use scrolling to achieve this. Try below code.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("testimonials"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element);
actions.perform();
```

Hope this help!